# How to kill a process running in specific script

Tags: shell-script, process, kill

I have two script files running simultaneously. I just need to kill the `java` process running in one script without affecting the `java` process in the another one.

Comment: In both scripts you can get the process id of the java application. E.g  `runJavaApp &` then in the next line `scr1javaAppId=$!`  You can kill the running process using `kill -s 15 $scr1javaAppid`

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the script itself, or are you trying to do this by hand from outside the scripts? The above comment only applies in the first case.

Answer (score 2):

```
pgrep -x script1 | xargs -I pid pkill -x -P pid java
```

Would kill the `java` processes whose parent process is called `script1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement it, to make it robust, to avoid race on temp files and etc.. but just that you are able to start with:

```
script1:
# add the line:
# $! returns the process id  of last job run in background
java -jar myjar1 &
echo $! > /tmp/script1.txt
...
# kill the script 2
# -9 SIGKILL or -15 SIGTERM
kill -9 `cat /tmp/script2.txt`

script2:
# add the line:
# $! returns the process id  of last job run in background
java -jar myjar2 &
echo $! > /tmp/script2.txt
...
# kill the script 1
# -9 SIGKILL or -15 SIGTERM
kill -9 `cat /tmp/script1.txt`
```

to make it better you could check if the file exist before to "cat it" with

```
if [ -e "/tmp/scriptN.txt" ]; then
    kill -9 `cat /tmp/scriptN.txt`
fi
```

Comment: `kill -9` is the worst idea I've ever seen. `kill -9` doesn't send a signal to the parent process which subsequently will signal it's children to finish work. It just kills the process without notification. You'd need to send the `SIGTERM` to the process. Another clean way to kill the process is using `pkill` which will defaultly send `SIGTERM`. Though  `pkill` is not availiable on all modern OS'es.

Comment: i gave him the option.. he can simply decide.. its in the comment -9 or -15..btw kill send as well, as default SIGTERM. man 1 kill, if you need help.